# How do I get the Value of a specified Key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I know this question has been asked a million times, I just can't seem to make the answers I find fix my problem.
All I'm trying to do is return the Value of the key that is specified.  They Key is in the variable "t":

```
RefDataTables.forEach(function(t, ti) {
  response.body = JSON.stringify(RefData_UpdateTracker.response.data[0].t);
});
```

I know the ".t" is wrong because that is looking for a property (I'm not sure the right word to call it) named "t"

Since "t = "HandleType"" What I'm trying to accomplish is the equivalent of:

```
response.body = JSON.stringify(RefData_UpdateTracker.response.data[0].HandleType)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by passing the variable between the square brackets.

```
response.body = JSON.stringify(RefData_UpdateTracker.response.data[0][t])
```

Comment: Thankyou!   I kept thinking a "." was needed between the [] brackets, and kept trying it that way (data[0].[t]) Never tried it like you put.   That was the trick.  And makes sense now that I think about it.